# How do I start a New Game Plus in Fiz?

Tags: fiz

I've completed the story questline, and I want to start a New Game Plus. I can't for the life of me find the button even though I've combed all the screens. Which screen is it on, and where on the screen? I've probably missed it in my carelessness...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D'oh! You can't start a New Game Plus from your old save game. You have to start it at the main menu, by choosing an empty save slot.